# Get ViewModel binded to HTML element Kendo UI MVVM

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm using Telerik's Kendo UI. I've binded a ViewModel object to a html element like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="stub">
  First Name: <span data-bind="value: name" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
kendo.bind($("#stub"), myViewModel);
```

Later in the code I'm losing the reference to the `myViewModel` object. Is it possible to retrieve this reference from the HTML (DOM) element that was binded with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that it's possible via DOM's object properties created by Kendo, i.e. `kendoBindingTarget.source`.

Full code:

```
var myViewModel = $("#stub").get(0).kendoBindingTarget.source;
```

Answer (score 0):

More correct way will be

```
var myViewModel = $("#stub [data-bind]").get(0).kendoBindingTarget.source;
```

Answer (score 0):

In binding place

```
kendo.bind($("#stub"), myViewModel);
$("#stub").data("viewModel", myViewModel);
```

Then in another place

```
var viewModel = $("#stub").data("viewModel");
```